# one variable show other not, when pass post ajax in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, ajaxform

I don't Why I get this error,

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

same thing I used in another post request ajax I got all variable.

but here I only get `frm` variable but not `pk` .

HTML

```
<form id="message-form" action="message/message_form/" user_id="{{u.id}}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="text" class="col-10">
                    {{ msgform.text }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <button id="submit" class="btn"  type="submit"><img height="30px" src="/static/img/send-button.png" alt="send"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br>
    </form>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var frm = $('#message-form');
        var id;
        id =   frm.attr("user_id"); 

        frm.submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr("method"),
                url: frm.attr("action"),
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", pk:id, frm:frm},
                error: function(data) {
                   // $("#MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something went wrong!");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
        new_msg = request.POST.get('text')
        print(new_msg)
        form = MessageForm()
//I GET ERROR HERE MY PK VARIBLE NOT PRESENT IN REQUEST POST
        print('request.id is here',request.POST.get['pk'])
        u = get_object_or_404(User,pk=request.POST['pk'])
        msg = message.objects.filter(sender=request.user).filter(receiver=u).all() | message.objects.filter(sender=u).filter(receiver=request.user).all() 
        if form.is_valid():
            smg = form.save(commit=False)
            smg.sender = request.user
            smg.receiver = u
            smg.save()
            if request.user != u and User.objects.filter(receiver__receiver=u,receiver__read=False).exists:
                notify.send(request.user, recipient=u, verb="message you please read in message box",public=False)
        msg = message.objects.filter(sender=request.user).filter(receiver=u).all() | message.objects.filter(sender=u).filter(receiver=request.user).all() 
        data = { "messages":msg}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

**Edit**

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = message
        fields = ('text','image')
        widgets = {
        # <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)">

            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1.5,'placeholder':"Enter message",'type':'text',
                          'class':'form-control','aria-label':"Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)",}),
        }
```

**Error**

```
Internal Server Error: /message/message_form/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner     
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response 
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response 
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\publish\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch       
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\publish\studentcollegeworld\messaging\views.py", line 23, in post
    print('request.id is here',request.POST.get['pk'])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
[12/Jun/2020 10:48:01] "POST /message/message_form/ HTTP/1.1" 500 88429
```

the main problem is `pk` variable not showing in post  data

Comment: Could you add the full stacktrace for the exception as well as the code for MessageForm()?

Comment: @Omar I Edited please check question. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `pk` back as a hidden input to your form

```
<form [...]>
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{u.id}}">
[...]
</form>
```

Comment: thank you . Your answer worked.  But why mine code is not working..

Comment: @AmarRokade Your form only contains fields for text and image, not user. Also sending the user_id in the form tag won't do anything.

Comment: okay, It means when submit form  we can't send `attr` value ? we have  to include in form as in answer.   thank you